# CSS 'gap' property doesn't work for fixed size flexbox with flex wrap enabled

Tags: css, flexbox

This is my code:

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: calc(100% - 60px);
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container>div {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    flex: 0 0 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #808080;
}
```

Here's a screenshot from my browser:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8kcf.png)

I expected to get the same gap for both horizontal and vertical direction, but it completely ignores my property set in CSS and shows much more space in vertical direction.

I've also tried to set `column-gap` and `row-gap` separately, but it doesn't change anything.
With `flex-wrap` disabled, the gap works as I expected.

Edit: Remove `position: absolute;` should work but it is not a good solution for me as it can no longer be placed on top of another element.

Comment: You need to add `align-content: top` to the container.

Comment: Tried, but still not working

Comment: Remove `position: absolute;`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-lhttyo?file=style.css

Comment: It's not a good solution cause it will damage my layout, as I can't overlay it onto another element

Comment: You can wrap the container with another div and only apply `position: absolute` to the outer div.